# ASP.NET MVC View Model - How do I display data in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and it seems ViewModels are the recommended way of passing data from a Controller to a View and allowing for more than one Model to be used in a View. Therefore I've created ProductViewModel which has the following:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductDescription> ProductDescriptions { get; set; }
```

In my controller I have:

```
        ProductViewModel productViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
        productViewModel.Products = db.Products.ToList();
        productViewModel.ProductDescription = db.ProductDescription.ToList();

        return View(productViewModel);
```

And the problem I'm having is looping over this data in the View. I can use `foreach` to iterate over for example `Products` but I don't know how to then combine this with `ProductDescription`:

```
@model Site.ViewModels.ProductListingViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ProductID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Color)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description???) - What do I actually need to write?
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Because the Description column is in `ProductDescription` it can't simply be accessed with `item.Description` because `item` specifically refers to `Products`. How should I do this?

Comment: create a DisplayTemplate for ProductDescription so the DisplayFor for ProductDescriptions shall work

Comment: Could you provide an example of that? Like I said I'm totally new to this and I have never heard of a DisplayTemplate before! :)

Comment: Surely a product description should be a property of product. What do you have separate collections?

Comment: I have no idea it wasn't me that made the database.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, i prefer for loop. why not use for loop?

```
@for (int i=0;i<Products.Count;i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(m => Products[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(m => ProductDescription[i].Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```